# Count number of groups in the regex pattern

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm using this code to count how many group of a regex pattern contain.

```
Dim GroupCount As Integer = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups.Count
```

It returns success when the pattern matches the input:

```
Dim GroupCount As Integer = Regex.Match(" something ", "( )something( )").Groups.Count
```

But it's always returns 1 if the pattern doesn't match.

```
Dim GroupCount As Integer = Regex.Match("ABC", "( )something( )").Groups.Count
```

What I need is a **function to count number of groups in a pattern** in any case.

Comment: What does that mean? `open bracket "(...)"`

Comment: @monocular I am curious to see 'pattern' you are using to match.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I mean i want to count how many group of a regex pattern contain. For example , this pattern have 3 group : (([a-z])([1-9]))

Comment: Does `\(` make sense? You must get count of matches.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan do you mean to apply the regex `\(` to the OP's patterns? That does not account for escaped `(`, `(` in character classes or all sorts of non-capturing groups in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`Regex.GetGroupNumbers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnumbers.aspx)?

```
Dim pattern As New Regex("( )something( )")
Dim groupCount As Integer = pattern.GetGroupNumbers().Length
```

By obtaining the result from a `Regex` object, it's independent of any particular match, which is just what you want.

You might want to subtract `1` from the result, because the entire string is also a group (at index `0`), depending on what you are looking for.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/aGzZjL)

Comment: Since this implies creating a RegEx instance, isn't there a memory / performance cost? Is there any static method to achieve this that would use the same cache as the other static functions from RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly then you need to count instances of **( )** in any word.Well If I am correct then this should help you;

```
Dim s As String = "( )yourstring()somevalue( )getit()"
            'A sample string.
Dim rgx As New Regex("(?<BraceGroup>\([ ]*\))", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            'Regex pattern to match '( )' or '()'.
Dim matches As MatchCollection = rgx.Matches(s)
            'Get all matches.
Dim count As Integer = matches.Count
            'Number of matches.
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total '() captures' found : {0}", count))
```

Ideone demo [here](http://ideone.com/4ZnasC).

Comment: Well, the regex methods and behaviour is all the same in VB.NET (after all they both just use .NET classes). For this example it's really just declarations and constructors that differ in syntax.

Answer (score -1):

[Read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx):

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match
>   An object that contains information about the match.

You need to test for GroupCount.Success.

Comment: The OP mentions that he knows that if the match fails, it will return a Count 1. This answer does not answer the main question which is to get the groups count even though there is no match.